# Python - Get unique website changes

Tags: html, string, python-3.x, search, web

This might be a strange question, probably why I haven't found an answer to it yet too.

I'm getting into Python and have set myself on a project, I need some help with something though.

I need a way to get unique website changes.

I want it to work on different sites simply by inputting the URL (got this working and all).

So to illustrate it.

Let's imagine I have a big website, but I'll make a simple illustration.
The original HTML could look like this:

```
<html>
     <body>
          <nav>
               <a>Home</a>
               <a>About</a>
          </nav>

          <section>
              Search!
          </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

But then for example if we searched for something(if the page was like: search.php?q=), I would like to get the change, and only the change in the website.

So lets say I searched for apples and the page (still the same page as above), it gives us this:

```
<html>
     <body>
          <nav>
               <a>Home</a>
               <a>About</a>
          </nav>

          <section>
              You searched for apples!
          </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I would want to only get this unique change in the website, like the string "You searched for apples!". Simply stripping the HTML of its tags won't be enough, then (like in the example) we would get the word Home and About too.

This would be A LOT easier if I just wanted this for a specific site, and then use something like beautifulsoup, but as said, I want this to work across different sites.

I know this is possible since I've seen it before.
Thanks for any and all help! Means a lot!

Comment: Why do you want this? Regardless you seem to basically want a diff

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of many imo although its subjective and im sure you will get many answers is as @Pardraic Cunningham said. Use a difference checker, python comes with [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html). You could download the text from the url and compare the previous version with the new version, something like this:

```
import urllib2
import difflib
file1 = "myFile1.txt"
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.example.com/test.html", "test.txt")
file2= "test.text"
diff = difflib.ndiff(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines())
```

This may or may not be ideal but seems a good place to start researching.

Comment: Firstly, if I try this it says that str has no attribute readlines. I also tried with simply giving it normal strings, but then it gives me something like: <generator object Differ.compare at 0x000001A43E77F0A0> Which I'm looking into why exactly (seems to just be returning the object and not the value)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to avoid object outputs and print the proper output 
just replace your print statement line with this :

```
print ('\n'.join(diff)) # diff is an object which contains the comparison output
```

it worked for me and it will work for you.